# No JDK found installing Apache NetBeans IDE on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: java, macos, installation, netbeans, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to install Apache NetBeans IDE on my MacOS Big Sur, but it fails at the beginning

[image]

This is my java -version

[image]

I tried to edit the .profile or .bash_profile for the java_home as some people said in other answers, but it did nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I did here was the combining of the answers I received.

I installed the latest Apache NetBeans IDE which is the 12.1.

**Right-click** on : Apache NetBeans 12.1.app -> Show package contents

**Go to** : /Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/etc

**Open** 'netbeans.conf' with text editor.

**Search for** : #netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"

**Add the path** to your JDK below like this :

netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home"

**Save**.

**Run the program.**

Comment: But, where do you even get 'Apache Netbeans 12.1.app'? Aren't you describing a failure to run the **installer**? It's the installer that's failing with that msg for me, leaving no .app folder at all.

Comment: I tried installing multiple versions of NetBeans, but none of them were working, then I installed the 12.1 version. First time, it didn't work, second time, it worked but I had to do the steps I explained in this answer. I later found it was a problem from MacOS new version. Couldn't really point what it was, but with the updates, now any version seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Java 8.

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

If you end up in `Error: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps:` due to prior workarounds with different instructions, specify the absolute location like this:

```
brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

Once the installation is complete, add `JAVA_HOME` to `~/.profile` and source it.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

To install NetBeans IDE, issue

```
brew cask install netbeans
```

Comment: Still no JDK found when trying to install it. My java version now : https://i.imgur.com/uAaCcI1.png

Comment: @CloudData What do you see when running javac -version after JDK8 installation?

Comment: javac 1.8.0_265

Comment: @CloudData What version of NetBeans IDE you're installing?

Comment: Apache NetBeans 12, I tried with the 11 too, same problem.

Comment: @CloudData what command are you  issuing to install netbeans?

Comment: brew cask install netbeans or  the Apache NetBeans 12.0.pkg. Both have errors, telling me to install the jdk. Terminal : https://i.imgur.com/iUvOrEV.png . Pkg : https://i.imgur.com/pOJJZaZ.png

Comment: I'm also running into the same issue, were you able to resolve this issue @CloudData ?

Comment: @being_j I went back to Catalina and I experienced no problems.

Comment: Same bug since yesterday I upgraded to Big Sur ... any solution? it's maddening ... Apple or Oracle's fault?

Comment: I had to run `brew install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8` (no "cask")

Answer (score 2):

I So the procedures with setting java_home and that stuff did not work for me. What I did is download the binary zip from netbeans, and opened etc/netbeans.conf. In here, you can simply set the path to your JDK `(netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home")`, where you'll need to remove the # in front of this line. If you now run bin/netbeans in this folder, you can run netbeans. Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative i found is to install netbeans using homebrew package repository with command which will install netbeans on your machine.

```
brew install netbeans
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Java is usually already installed in Mac OS. Netbeans installation sometimes is the problem. I had the same issue. I resolved it by installing netbeans using `brew cask install netbeans`. Use the command line instead of trying to download netbeans from the web.

Answer (score 0):

I did this procedure: [Installing Netbeans 8.2 on MacOS Big Sur no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494505/installing-netbeans-8-2-on-macos-big-sur-no-jdk-found).

I installed Java 8 and Netbeans 12.1. I couldn’t install Netbeans 8.2, fortunately the installer imports Netbeans 8.2 preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I used Netbeans 8.2 with JDK 8u111.

You can download this version of Netbeans in this link:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html