# No Java Found and No JDK Found when installing NetBeans on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: java, netbeans

I got a tough issue when trying to installing NetBeans.
I have JDK 8 on my machine but want to use JDK 11 for NetBeans. So I installed AdoptOpenJDK 11 and set the java home path in .bash-profile.
However, I still got the "No JDK Found problem" on Mac. So I tried to remove the older JDK folder and uninstall the older java using the commands below:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

But this seems to result in a critical problem. The NetBeans installer says "No Java Found", although I've already installed AdoptOpenJDK 11, and I also tried to install Oracle JDK using their installer.

JAVA path in .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Issues when installing NetBeans:

[image]

EDIT: The NetBeans version I tried to install is 12.0. The JDK version I tried to use is AdoptOpenJDK 11 and Oracle JDK 11 (either can work for NetBeans)

Comment: Open Terminal and then open Preferences. Click the General tab. Look at the second cluster of controls, where it reads "Shells open with..." and tell us whether you've selected the default or command radio button.

Comment: NetBeans appears hellbent on installing itself using JDK 8, but your JDK 8 installation is no longer valid. Rather than trying to get NetBeans to use JDK 11 instead, just follow the advice in that error message, and _"download and install the latest update of Java 8....and restart NetBeans installation"_. Once you have successfully installed NetBeans using JDK 8, it is trivial to upgrade to another JDK using **Tools > Java Platforms...**. Also, update your question to state which version of NetBeans you are trying to install, since that might also be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Does this help?... [Installing Netbeans 8.2 on MacOS Big Sur no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64494505/2985643)

Comment: Installing JDK 8 still doesn't work. The NetBeans can find the JRE but still prompts "No JDK found"...

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a successful installing on Big Sur.

First, please install NetBeans 12.3 instead of LTS 12.0

[image]

Second, Oracle JDK 11 seems to have some bugs when working with NetBeans. NB often quits unexpectedly and almost can't be used normally(if your NB quit unexpectedly with an auto-generated terminal command in the code block below, we are in the same case). So I use AdoptOpenJDK 11 as a workaround. Note that for myself, I deleted all the JDKs except for this one, as the expectation still occurs even though I have already configured the java path in .bash_profile.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java ; exit;
```

Thanks for all your comments and wish you a good experience with NetBeans!