# Netbeans 8.2 installation Error [No JDK found] in mac m1

Tags: java, macos, installation, java-8, netbeans-8.2

I tried to install Netbeans 8.2 in my macOS Monterey 12.0.1 but it's giving me the error **NO JDK FOUND**.

[image]

And I have already installed JDK 8...

[image]

My System Preferences are

[image]

Please anyone help me with this error....

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Found a guide on [this website](https://orclqa.com/netbeans-jdk-is-missing-error-mac/). Basically open Terminal and enter `echo $JAVA_HOME` Then copy the path you get to your clipboard. Find the netbeans.conf file. It might be somewhere similar to `/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc`. Finally, paste that path you found earlier after `netbeans_jdkhome=` inside the quotation marks.

Should look something like `netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Comment: Sir, I can't even install Netbeans then how can I set Netbeans config.

Comment: You make a good point. Here are some alternative solutions that worked for different people https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570470/no-jdk-found-installing-apache-netbeans-ide-on-macos-big-sur