# How to use an SDKMAN jdk for window applications on mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, netbeans, sdkman

I've recently installed a fresh Mac OS and installed java using SDKMAN but no windows apps recognize the jdk throwing a java not installed error. Trying to install NetBeans using the .pkg throws a similar error.

Meanwhile, all terminal apps like gradle have no problem with the JDK that was installed using SDKMAN.

How can I use the jdk installed with SDKMAN with windowed apps in Mac?

Comment: Apps for Microsoft Windows do not run on macOS. So your Question makes no sense. Edit for clarity.

Comment: For NetBeans on macOS, download the `.dmg` file. Currently that would be `Apache-NetBeans-14-bin-macosx.dmg`.

Comment: [1] Not a solution to your specific problem, but a possible workaround is to bypass the installer completely, simply [download and unzip the NetBeans binary zip file **netbeans-14-bin.zip**](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb14/nb14.html) [2] See the accepted answer to [No JDK found installing Apache NetBeans IDE on MacOS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63570470/2985643). Does that help? [3] Provide more details in your question; just stating _"throwing a java not installed error"_ is inadequate. Provide the context, the precise error in text form, and a screen shot.

Comment: It was the same problem as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63570470/2985643) @skomisa though instead of using brew, I installed both via dmg and then deleted the dmg java to leave just the ones in sdkman.

Comment: OK. Though similar, your solution seems sufficiently different to avoid being a duplicate. Please consider posting (and accepting) an answer here, providing a similar level of detail to the accepted answer to the linked question. Your solution can then help others with a similar problem in the future. Also please be sure to specify your versions of NetBeans and Java.

Answer (score 1):

[Checking this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570470/no-jdk-found-installing-apache-netbeans-ide-on-macos-big-sur) I've solved it by temporarily installing a similar Java in question through the .dmg file. After that, I've installed Netbeans 14 through the .dmg file as well.

Once NetBeans was installed, I deleted the Java installed through the dmg to manage all my JDKs through sdkman. Since sdkman sets java_home, NetBeans continued to work without a problem.

For some reason, NetBeans installer doesn't detect the current java by the java_home environment but through something else. But NetBeans works without a problem.